# Implementing Varnish on a server with legacy websites running on it

Tags: varnish

Is it destined for dissaster to implement Varnish on an server with lot's of websites from years back hosted on it? Are there caveats, workarounds, do's and dont's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish is a transparent cache proxy. It doesn't care how old your websites are. So it will work just fine.